# Posts is null when i return

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, asynchronous, firebase-realtime-database

```
Future<List<Post>> selectPopularDestination() async {
    List<Post> posts = [];
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('posts');

    await dbRef
        .orderByChild('postTime')
        .limitToFirst(4)
        .onChildAdded.forEach((element) {
          Post post = Post.fromJson(element.snapshot.value);
          print(post.toString());
          posts.add(post);
        });

    return posts;
}
```

Comment: What you are getting here `print(post.toString());`

Comment: It's easier to support if you show your `element.snapshot.value` output value as well as your `Post.fromJson` code